# R, R6 Operator Overloading

Tags: r, operator-keyword, r6

Consider the following:

```
A = R6::R6Class("ClassA")
B = R6::R6Class("ClassB")

`+.ClassA` = function(o1,o2) o1 #Trivial Example, Usually do something
`+.ClassB` = function(o1,o2) o1 #Trivial Example, Usually do something

a = A$new()
b = B$new()

a + b
```

Which throws an error:

```
Warning: Incompatible methods ("+.ClassA", "+.ClassB") for "+"
Error in a + b : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

How can the above be resolved, so both `A` and `B` can overload the `+` operator, and be added together.

Answer (score 9):

Thought I would post my answer, I assign the class `'IAddable'` to both R6 prototypes (sort of like interface declaration in other languages)

```
A = R6::R6Class(c("ClassA","IAddable"))
B = R6::R6Class(c("ClassB","IAddable"))
```

Then we can assign a single overloaded operator, which will be called by all objects that inherit from this interface class declaration.

```
`+.IAddable` = function(o1,o2) o1 #Trivial Example, Usually do something
```

This then works as expected:

```
a = A$new()
b = B$new()

a + b  #WORKS, RETURNS a
b + a  #WORKS, RETURNS b
```